# Multiple space-delimited Google Admin SDK scopes causing invalid_scope error

Tags: authentication, google-admin-sdk, scopes

*NOTE - Since I am new to StackOverflow and only permitted two links, I've had to modify my URL snippets below and use backslashes after the https: since the editor thinks I'm writing URLs.*

I have successfully accessed our G Suite Admin SDK directory users and groups APIs, but it only works when, as I request an access code, I specify one scope or the other in the URL:

"...?response_type=code&**scope=https:\\www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user**&redirect_uri=..."

and

"...?response_type=code&**scope=https:\\www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group**&redirect_uri=..."

both work, but when I try:

"...?response_type=code&**scope=https:\\www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user%20https:\\www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group**&redirect_uri=..."

I get an invalid_scope error, even though the documentation says to space-delimit multiple scopes. (I've also tried a plus-sign instead of a space (%20), since I've seen that in some examples, but no luck there either.) Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you need the multi-scopes for?

Comment: I'm planning to use Filemaker to automate some of our G Suite user and group management tasks.